# Bash Comma Delimited List Extracting Last Column

Tags: regex, bash

I have a comma delimited list in a txt file in bash that looks like this:

```
name1,org2,enabled,email
name2,org1,enabled,email
name3,org3,enabled,
name4,org4,enabled,email
name5,org5,enabled,
```

I want a command that will extract the rows of the people who are missing their e-mails, what is a command that will do that? Thanks

```
awk -<Flag> <don't know the syntax>
```

Answer (score 3):

In awk:

```
$ awk -F, '$4==""' file
name3,org3,enabled,
name5,org5,enabled,
```

- `-F,` defines `FS`, the input file separator
- `$4==""` outputs records where 4th field is empty

`grep`:

```
$ grep ",$" file
name3,org3,enabled,
name5,org5,enabled,
```

- `,$` returns records where the last field is empty

Comment: or `awk -F, '$4=="" {print $1}' file`

Comment: It is more descriptive.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that your file contains lines like:
`name1,org2,enabled,email@domain.com` and **not**  `name1,org2,enabled,email`

Based on that, you can use `grep -v` (invert), i.e.:

```
grep -v '@' file
```

---

Output:

```
name3,org3,enabled,
name5,org5,enabled,
```

Comment: Nice out of the box thinking!

Answer (score 1):

This could be awk command similar to the code below:

```
awk -F, '$4 == ""'
```

This code assumes:

1. each line is comma separated string
2. 4th field could be empty
3. if the item 2 is true, print the whole line

Edit:
Early I have shared the shorter way with `!$4`. But this one is not good approach. For details look for discussions in the comments to my post.

Comment: `!$4`evaluates to true also when `$4==0` which is not the same as `$4==""`.

Comment: Agree. `!$4` is not good approach. The better is to be more specific. So `$4 == ""` is the best approach.

Answer (score 0):

***grep*** approach:

```
grep -Eo '([^[:space:]]*,){3}$' file
```

The output:

```
name3,org3,enabled,
name5,org5,enabled,
```

---

***sed*** approach:

```
sed -n '/\(\S*,\)\{3\}$/p' file
```